# Show only those rows of selected objects whose sub object has a specific value using AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

**Following is the JSON being used**
Its contains an array of objects (branch). Then those objects have sub-object called "service". I am trying to show branch name and its services. But only those with type **cream**.

```
[
  {
    "b_sn": "1",
    "b_name": "Alambagh",
    "service": [
      {
        "i_sn": "1",
        "i_name": "Vanilla",
        "i_type": "cream",
        "i_detail": ""
      },
      {
        "i_sn": "2",
        "i_name": "Orange",
        "i_type": "candy",
        "i_detail": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "b_sn": "2",
    "b_name": "Aminabad",
    "service": [
      {
        "i_sn": "3",
        "i_name": "Butterscotch",
        "i_type": "cream",
        "i_detail": ""
      },
      {
        "i_sn": "4",
        "i_name": "Blueberry",
        "i_type": "cream",
        "i_detail": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "b_sn": "3",
    "b_name": "Hazratganj",
    "service": [
      {
        "i_sn": "1",
        "i_name": "Orange",
        "i_type": "candy",
        "i_detail": ""
      },
      {
        "i_sn": "2",
        "i_name": "Mango",
        "i_type": "candy",
        "i_detail": ""
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to display only those rows who have `i_type ="cream"`, if any branch (object) does not have any number of sub-property "cream" then its `b_name` should not be displayed in the table.

Following is HTML code of the page:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>SN.</th>
    <th>Branch Name</th>
    <th>Services</th>
  </tr>
  <tr data-ng-repeat="br in branches">
    <td>{{br.b_sn}}.</td>
    <td>{{br.b_name}}</td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <th></th>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="i in br.service">
          <td style="width:70%">{{i.i_sn}}. {{i.i_name}}</td>
          <td>{{i.detail}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: you might need a custom filter for your first `ng-repeat`

Comment: @Aleksey Solovey thanks for replying.  I tried  <tr data-ng-repeat="i in br.service| filter: { c_type: 'cream'}. It worked partially, as c_type was sorted but those branches which dont have crean type are still being display wit no sub values.

Comment: your question is a bit too broad or confusing. I suggest creating a simple, **custom** filter for your logic. Here is my attempt at this: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/NBgaksxLJT5H4RODATrT?p=preview). I filter out everything that doesn't have "i_type" set as "cream" for all elements of the row. Feel free to modify the code

Comment: @AlekseySolovey - Thanks! But I want to display each branch with service i_type=cream. But your code is displaying only those branch with all i_type cream.

Comment: @AlekseySolovey - Thank you. Your code really helped. I have made few modifications. I have posted the solution in the Answer section. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the help.
I got my solution. Here is the code for the above problem.

```
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

      <table class="table">
        <tr>
          <th>SN.</th>
          <th>Branch Name</th>
          <th>Services</th>
        </tr>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="br in branches | myFilter: {'key':key}">
          <td>{{br.b_sn}}.</td>
          <td>{{br.b_name}}</td>
          <td>
            <table>
              <tr data-ng-repeat="i in br.service|filter :{i_type:'cream'}">
                <td>{{i.i_sn}}. {{i.i_name}}</td>
                <td>{{i.detail}}</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>

    </div>

    <script>
      var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
      app.filter('myFilter', function() {
        return function(json, input) {
          console.log(json, input);
          var new_json = [];
          for(var i=0; i<json.length; i++){
            var flag = false;
            for(var j=0; j<json[i].service.length; j++){
              if(json[i].service[j].i_type == input.key){
                flag = true;
                  break;
              }
              else{
                flag = false;

              }
            }
            if(flag){
              new_json.push(json[i]);
            }
          }
          return new_json;
        };
      });
      app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.key = "cream";
        $scope.branches = [
          {
            "b_sn": "1",
            "b_name": "Alambagh",
            "service": [
              {
                "i_sn": "1",
                "i_name": "Vanilla",
                "i_type": "cream",
                "i_detail": ""
              },
              {
                "i_sn": "2",
                "i_name": "Orange",
                "i_type": "candy",
                "i_detail": ""
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "b_sn": "2",
            "b_name": "Aminabad",
            "service": [
              {
                "i_sn": "3",
                "i_name": "Butterscotch",
                "i_type": "cream",
                "i_detail": ""
              },
              {
                "i_sn": "4",
                "i_name": "Blueberry",
                "i_type": "cream",
                "i_detail": ""
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "b_sn": "3",
            "b_name": "Hazratganj",
            "service": [
              {
                "i_sn": "1",
                "i_name": "Orange",
                "i_type": "candy",
                "i_detail": ""
              },
              {
                "i_sn": "2",
                "i_name": "Mango",
                "i_type": "candy",
                "i_detail": ""
              }
            ]
          }
        ];

      });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

For branches, that has no service of type 'cream', you can write a function that filters all of the services that particular branch has and if no service with type 'cream' is found then return false i.e, don't show that branch.

Similarly, for the services, you can manually check each service whether it has type cream, this way you will be only printing `branches` that has type `cream` in them and `services` that are of type `cream`

something like this:

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <th>SN.</th>
     <th>Branch Name</th>
     <th>Services</th>
   </tr>
   <tr ng-if="creamCheck(br)" data-ng-repeat="br in branches">
     <td>{{br.b_sn}}.</td>
     <td>{{br.b_name}}</td>
     <td>
        <table>
           <th></th>
           <tr ng-if="i.i_type==='cream'" data-ng-repeat="i in br.service">
             <td style="width:70%">{{i.i_sn}}. {{i.i_name}}</td>
             <td>{{i.detail}}</td>
           </tr>
        </table>
     </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

and write the `creamCheck` function as:

```
 $scope.creamCheck = function(branch)
    {
        var arr = ($filter('filter')(branch.service, { i_type: 'cream' }));
        if (arr.length>0) {
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
```

this should about do the trick